# Haskell's $ (function application operator) in CoffeeScript?

Tags: haskell, coffeescript, functional-programming

In CoffeeScript, does there exist a concept similar to Haskell's $ operator? I can't seem to find anything on the subject, but I believe I have once seen an issue on GitHub.

What I would like to do is write

```
foo = bar $ baz 1 2
```

instead of

```
foo = bar (baz 1 2)
```

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1614

Comment: You might like piping operator in <| LiveScript: http://livescript.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the above posted GitHub issue, it seems that has been heavily debated more than one time. There's no conclusion however, but it doesn't seem like it's something that's going to be included.

One guy, [alexkg](https://github.com/alexkg), implemented the feature in [his own fork](https://github.com/alexkg/coffee-script) of CoffeeScript, naming the operator `<-`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may be slightly confused about what exactly `$` does in Haskell.

As you can see from [its type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-36-) -- `(a -> b) -> a -> b` -- `$` only "knows" about two arguments.

Therefore, in your `foo = bar $ baz 1 2` examples, `$` doesn't "know" about `baz 1 2`.

The reason the grouping occurs the way it does is because "function application has higher precedence than **any** infix operator" ([source](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html)).  So the same expression using the infix operator `.`, for example, is parsed exactly the same way:

```
foo = bar . baz 1 2  -- also parsed as `bar (baz 1 2)`
                     --   because of function application's high precedence
```

Thus, the only thing `$` does is take two arguments and apply the first to the second.  As long as Coffeescript allows higher-order functions, it's trivial to implement `$`.  The rest of the behavior you've noticed is part of the Haskell language.